# Factorization of a (Simple) Multi-Variate Polynomial over a Finite Field

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, multivalued-functions

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field where $q$ a prime, and consider a multi-variate polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_q[X_1, X_2, \dots, X_\ell]$ of the following form:

$\begin{align}\tag{1}
f(X_1, \dots, X_\ell) =\sum_{a_i \in \{0, 1\}, i \in [\ell]}c_{a_1, \dots, a_\ell}X_1^{a_1}X_2^{a_2}\dots X_\ell^{a_\ell}.
\end{align}$

### Motivation

When $f(X_1,\dots,X_\ell)$ is expressed as in the above form, we need to store $c_{a_1, \dots, a_\ell}$ for all $(a_1, \dots, a_\ell)\in \{ 0, 1\}^\ell$, which would require $O(2^\ell \log q)$ bits **in the worst case**. However, for every $f(X_1, \dots, X_\ell) \in \mathbb{F}_q[X_1, X_2, \dots, X_\ell]$, if we were able to factor $f(X_1,\dots,X_\ell)$ as

$\begin{align}\tag{2}
f(X_1, \dots, X_\ell) =c_0 \cdot \prod_{i \in [\ell]}(X_i + c_i ), 
\end{align}$

then we would only require $O(\ell \log q)$ bits by storing only $c_0$ and $\{c_i\}_{i \in [\ell]}$. In fact, it would still be useful if the above can be expressed as

$\begin{align}\tag{3}
f(X_1, \dots, X_\ell) = \sum_{t = [L]}c_{t,0} \cdot \prod_{i \in [\ell]}(X_i + c_{t,i}), 
\end{align}$

for a small enough $L$, such as $L=2$ or $L=O(\log \ell)$. In this case we would require $O(\ell L \log q)$ bits.

### Question

For every multi-variate polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_q[X_1, X_2, \dots, X_\ell]$ with the restriction that each degree is at most 1, can we express it as Eq.(2) or Eq.(3)??

---

The reason behind Eq.(3) stems from the fact that, there exit univariate polynomials $f(X)$ over $\mathbb{F}_q[X]$ such that $f(X)$ does not factor into a product of degree one polynomials, e.g., $X^4+1$. Although it is not completely relevant, it seemed to me that there might exist some polynomials $f(X_1, \dots, X_\ell)$ such that it can not be expressed as Eq.(2).

Comment: I think it is impossible. Basically exactly because there are $q^{2^\ell}$ distinct polynomials of the form (1) and much less of those of form (2). To give concrete examples I would go to the case $q=2$. when we see that (provided $c_0\neq0$) a polynomial $f$ of form (2) has exactly one input where it does not vanish. Similarly a polynomial of the form (3) will have exactly $t$ inputs where it won't vanish. But in this case the class of polynomials of the form (1) gives rise to ALL the functions from $\Bbb{F}_2^n\to\Bbb{F}_2$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks! I like the way you showed it through a simple counting type argument. I think you're absolutely right.